# Android Retrofit 2 complex object mapping using SimpleXMLConverterFactory

Tags: android, object, mapping, retrofit2

My Complex XML structure https://www.uj.ac.za/studyatUJ/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('aps_score_card')/items() beautified here : https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer

I have added my XML mapping objects with the top one ApsScoreCard containing a list of ContentScore which contains one Score.
Each of these are elements in the XML structure provided above.

I can't seem to map to the Element (and subsequent siblings, but for simplicity sake):  `

```
<d:APS ...>some_value</d:APS>`
```

I don't know if my Object mapping is wrong or some other error because I seem to get the right amount of scores = 10 but not a single value of d:APS.

```
public interface ProgrammeCourseClientApi {
   @GET("lists/getbytitle('aps_score_card')/items()")
   Call<ApsScoreCard> loadApsScoreCard();
}

public class ProgrammeCourseRetrofit  {

static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.uj.ac.za/studyatUJ/_api/web/";

public static ProgrammeCourseClientApi buildProgrammeCourseClient() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    okHttpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);

    Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.createNonStrict(
                    new Persister(
                            new AnnotationStrategy()
                    )
            ));

    Retrofit retrofit = retrofitBuilder
            .client(okHttpClientBuilder.build())
            .build();

    ProgrammeCourseClientApi clientApi = retrofit.create(ProgrammeCourseClientApi.class);

    return clientApi;
}
}


@Root(name = "m:properties", strict = false)
public class Score {
@Element(name = "d:APS", required = false)
private double mAps;

public void setAps(double vAps) {
    mAps = vAps;
}

public double getAps() {
    return mAps;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Score : " + getAps();
}

    public Score() {

    }
}

@Root(name = "entry", strict = false)
public class ContentScore {

    @Element(name = "content", required = false)
    private Score mScore;

    public void setScore(Score vScore) {
        mScore = vScore;
    }

    public Score getScore() {
        return mScore;
    }
}

@Root (name = "feed", strict = false)
public class ApsScoreCard {

    @ElementList (name = "entry", inline = true, required = false)
    private ArrayList<ContentScore> mScoreList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setContentScoreList(ArrayList<ContentScore> vScoreList) {
        mScoreList = vScoreList;
    }

    public ArrayList<ContentScore> getContentScoreList() {
        return mScoreList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String list ="";
        for (int i = 0; i < getContentScoreList().size(); i++) {
            list += "\n" + getContentScoreList().get(i);
        }
        return list;
    }
}

public void loadRetrofitResults() {

        mProgrammeCourseClientApi = ProgrammeCourseRetrofit.buildProgrammeCourseClient();

        Call<ApsScoreCard> call = mProgrammeCourseClientApi.loadApsScoreCard();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ApsScoreCard>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ApsScoreCard> call, Response<ApsScoreCard> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if(response.body().getContentScoreList() != null) {
                        ApsScoreCard apsScoreCard = response.body();
                        Score score = apsScoreCard.getContentScoreList().get(2).getScore();
                        mTempText.setText(Integer.toString(apsScoreCard.getContentScoreList().size()) +
                                ", Value(2) = " + score);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response is onsuksesvol", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ApsScoreCard> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you missed a little when created POJO classes with annotations. 
I tried to add one more class and now your project works fine!

---

```
    @Root(name = "feed", strict = false)
    public class ApsScoreCard {

        @ElementList(name = "entry", inline = true, required = false)
        private ArrayList<ContentScore> mScoreList = new ArrayList<>();

        public void setContentScoreList(ArrayList<ContentScore> vScoreList) {
            mScoreList = vScoreList;
        }

        public ArrayList<ContentScore> getContentScoreList() {
            return mScoreList;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String list ="";
            for (int i = 0; i < getContentScoreList().size(); i++) {
                list += "\n" + getContentScoreList().get(i);
            }
            return list;
        }

    public class ContentProperties {
        @Element(name = "properties", required = false)
        private Score mScore;
    }

@Root(name = "entry", strict = false)
public class ContentScore {

    @Element(name = "content", required = false)
    private ContentProperties mProperties;
    //private Score mScore;

    @Element(name = "updated", required = false)
    private String mUpdated;
}

public class Score {
    @Element(name = "Created", required = false)
    private String mCreated;

    @Element(name = "APS", required = false, type = Float.class)
    private float mAps;
}
```

In ContentScore class you defined that Score class should be 'content' element but in Score class your declared that root element is 'properties'. I guess, one annotation just overrides another.

Note that in new implementation Score class has no @Root annotation.

If you add ContentProperties class it should solve problem. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. The extra class fixed it. XML structure threw me off.